# Depth first search to find path in graph

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, graph, depth-first-search

I am trying to find a path between two points in a graph using a depth first search in Python. The idea is to return a path (not necessarily the shortest) from point a to point b or an empty list if a path does not exist. I have a class which contains an adjacency list (dictionary called graph), a dictionary of visited nodes and a stack (a list called path) to track the current path. The recursive function I am using to do this is a method called getPath(self,a,b). The issue I am having is that I am unable to return the stack once I have found the target node, I think because the stack is just returned as part of a recursive call and the function continues running. What can I change to make this work? The code is as follows:

```
def getPath(self,a,b):
        self.visited["{}".format(a)]=1 #mark a as visited
        self.path.append("{}".format(a)) #add a to current path
        if ("{}".format(a)=="{}".format(b)): #check to see if we've reached our destination
            return self.path #here is where I would like the function to return the path
        else:
            for v in self.graph["{}".format(a)]:
                if self.visited[v]==0:
                    self.getPath(v,b)
            self.path.pop #remove v from our current path if we only find dead ends from its edges
```

Comment: The title and the question are inconsistent. Does it have to be shortest or not?

Comment: Thank you, fixed this now. It does not have to be the shortest path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code in the **else** block, you are returning nothing for the recursive call.

So, what if the children call:

```
self.getPath(v,b)
```

returns **self.path** but in the parent call of that function gonna return nothing.

So, you have to make some changes in the **else** block to keep track of these return values.

```
def getPath(self,a,b):
        self.visited["{}".format(a)]=1 #mark a as visited
        self.path.append("{}".format(a)) #add a to current path
        if ("{}".format(a)=="{}".format(b)): #check to see if we've reached our destination
            return self.path #here is where I would like the function to return the path
        else:
            for v in self.graph["{}".format(a)]:
                if self.visited[v]==0:
                    result = self.getPath(v,b)
                    if(result != None):
                        return result
            self.path.pop #remove v from our current path if we only find dead ends from its edges
            return None
```